# Whats a "[CS Format=A]" header is for?

Tags: file, compression, file-format

I'm trying to identify a type of file that contents starts with "[CS Format=A]".

I've extracted files from blobs from a database I was handed. I do not have access to the software that created this database. There is a column that I assume signifies compression (it's called COMPRESS). Also in said database were the names of the files and their extensions. I've extracted all the files out of the database and everything works except anything that's marked as compress is not readable as it's own file type (I.E. if it was a PDF before it was stored in this DB now that I've pulled them all back out it is not parsable as a pdf like the other non-"COMPRESS" pdfs).  When I crack them open and look at them the first 13 bytes always are "[CS Format=A]" (which I swear I've seen somewhere before, but can't for the life of me remember what) followed by binary data. Magic can't tell me what I'm looking at and google is not being very helpful with my very strict search term. These were stored in an MSSQL database before I was given the files, most likely 2005 by the time it was pulled.

Comment: This needs some context. Is this SQL? What language are you using?

Comment: Context would really help.. My Google-fu is weak today. :|

Comment: I've ran into a similar issue.  It was involving accessing data from a system from this company: http://www.inteum.com/  I worked around my issue by having the users of the system turn off compression.  I'm still curious to know what format this is.

Comment: Reverse the application that store those pdfs in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not helpful, but just to make sure... Oracle will decompress automatically on select.

If it's still compressed afterwards then you're looking at some 3rd party component which can be almost anything, but I'd start with testing Mac/Win first before you run through all the 3rd party compression tools.